# can you connect two mobile usb modem to access the internet

Tags: usb, usb-modem

i have two usb modem from different ISP provider, can i connect them simultaneous to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

On their own, no - Windows has no structure for dual-wan, but if you buy compatible USB modems that work with pfsense then you could combine, or use one as a failover - even assign certain devices different internet connections.